# Ошибка при подключении - путь не верный (path is not defined)

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-rigger

Стоит задача подключать html кусками.

Решил использовать для этого gulp-rigger, прочитал [статью на хабре](https://habr.com/post/250569/).

Тысячу раз изменил уже сам код в gulpfile.js, но всё равно html не инклюдится, галп пишет что путь не верный (**path is not defined**).

Первый вопрос: подскажите что не так с моим кодом и как исправить это?

**Код таска gulp-rigger в gulpfile.js**

```
> gulp.task('html:build', function () {
>     gulp.src(path.app/include/html) //Выберем файлы по нужному пути
>         .pipe(rigger()) //Прогоним через rigger
>         .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist/html)) //Выплюнем их в папку build
>         .pipe(reload({stream: true})); //И перезагрузим наш сервер для обновлений });
```

**Структура проекта**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Второй вопрос: возможно ли как-то автоматизировать сборку через gulp-rigger, а именно, чтобы при сборке проекта в dist html формировался в обычном виде (без //= header.html)?

За сборку проекта в dist отвечают .pipe(gulp.dest('')) в каждом моём таске, а окончательно проект собирается этим кодом:

```
gulp.task('watch', ['reload','css', 'html', 'img', 'fonts', 'js'], () => {
    gulp.watch('app/stylus/**/*.styl', ['css']);
    gulp.watch(['app/*.html'], ['html'])
    gulp.watch('dist/*.html', browserSync.reload)
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил свою проблему планином [gulp-file-include](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-file-include)
gulp-rigger толком не поддерживается с 2015 года

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/303417)

Comment: @Andrey, https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1639/178988. Впрочем, этот ответ всё равно неверный.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> gulp.src(path.app/include/html) //Выберем файлы по нужному пути
> ```

Да ну? А кто строки будет в кавычки заключать? И ещё через 2 строки то же самое.